# How to create an empty array in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, razor

In Javascript, doing:

```
var array = [];
```

creates an empty array. However when I try to do this in a Razor template it is telling me it is invalid. What is the way to create an empty array?

```
@foreach (var history in Model.table)
        {
            <tr>
                <td >@history.Comments</td>
                @if (@Model.ActiveUserClients.Count == @history.ClientBlockFlags.Count)
                {
                    var booleanValueTotal = [];
                    int a = 0;
                }
       etc...
```

I've tried:

```
var booleanValueTotal = [];
@{ var booleanValueTotal = []; }
```

I need to be able to push strings into the variable.

Comment: That's not HTML, that is some templating language – which one?

Comment: templating language then, i apologize, I just mean i'm using the cshtml file to write it not a js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Razor, and when you are in a Razor code block you don't write Javascript, you write C# code. So you probably want either a list:

```
var booleanValueTotal = new List<string>();
```

Which you can then push to like so:

```
booleanValueTotal.Add("some value");
```

Or, if the amount of items is already known, you can create an array:

```
var booleanValueTotal = new string[n];
booleanValueTotal[0] = "some value";
```

Comment: i need an array because im pushing strings into it, both of those dont seem to work

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example to push a string to them.